# Unable to remove the last + from the output of my python code

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a python code that takes a large number as input from a user and then prints the sum of the digits of the number as output. But in the output, there is an extra '+' which i want to remove. Pasting the code and the output for your reference.

```
    number = input('Enter a large Number: ')
    
    lists = [int(x) for x in str(number)]
    
    sofd = 0
    print('The sum of the digits: ', end = '')
    for i in lists:
      sofd = sofd + i
      print(i, end = '+')
    print(" = ",sofd)
```

and the output for this is as below:

```
    Enter a large Number: 35463392
    The sum of the digits: 3+5+4+6+3+3+9+2+ =  35
```

Any help in resolving this is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chandra.

Comment: Suspiciously it looks like that code comes from someone else. Scrap it and do it yourself,  after studying a bit of python.  If it's yours,  then there are still  quite a few things you need to sort out and understand first

Comment: `str.join` is precisely what you're looking for here, specifically `'+'.join(number)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called join which joins the elements in a list.
The usual syntax is => "+".join(lists)    // list of Strings
Since your list contains integers we will be using the following syntax.
And the "+" is the string that you want to join your elements with.

```
number = input('Enter a large Number: ')

lists = [int(x) for x in str(number)]

sofd = 0
print('The sum of the digits: ', end = '')
for i in lists:
  sofd = sofd + i
print('+'.join(str(x) for x in lists), end='')
print(" = ",sofd)
```

output

```
Enter a large Number: 123
The sum of the digits: 1+2+3 =  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i, number in enumerate(lists):
    sofd += number
    print(number, end="")
    if i != len(lists) - 1:
        print(" + ", end="")
print(" =", sofd)
```

Breaking It Down:

1. `enumerate(lists)`: This returns a list of tuples, each tuple being in format `(index, item)`.
2. `i != len(lists) - 1`: `i` is the index (starting at 0, of course), and `len(lists)` returns the length of the list. If we subtract one, we get the index of the last element in the list. Therefore, this is only True if it's not the last element in the list, and will print `+` if it's True.